# How to throw an object and have it rotate around a sphere as if it were orbiting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can pick up and throw an object by adding a force to it which throws it in the correct direction the player is facing. If this object was thrown and it's speed is greater than the speed `Threshold` it starts to `RotateAround` the planet which works fine.

Now what I'm trying to do is:

If I apply a force to the object whose speed is greater than the speed threshold upon throwing it, the object will go into orbit but not in the correct direction which would be the players forward direction.

[**Example Video** demonstrating the problem when I throw the frisbee (object)](https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/130a200q2C2l0P3E3s18/Screen%20recording%202017-10-01%20at%2002.03.42%20PM.mp4?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=2782700).

This is my code:

```
Vector3 planetDir = planet.transform.position - transform.position;
    Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.Normalize(planetDir), transform.forward);

    if (rb.velocity.magnitude * 10 > speedThreshold)
    {
        rb.isKinematic = true;
        isOrbiting = true;
    }
    if (isOrbiting == true)
    {
        transform.RotateAround(planet.transform.position, axis, rotationSpeed); //start orbiting

        desiredAltitude = (transform.position - planet.transform.position).normalized * radius +
                          planet.transform.position; //set the altitude
        transform.position = desiredAltitude; //move this gameobject to desired altitude
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work added a negative sign in front of the transform.forward, So this

```
      Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.Normalize(planetDir), 
transform.forward);
```

To This

```
Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.Normalize(planetDir), -
transform.forward);
```